# Change mintty keyboard shortcuts

Tags: msys2, mintty

mintty 2.8.5 for MSYS2 uses <kbd>Shift+Insert</kbd> for pasting. But on my laptop the <kbd>Insert</kbd> btn is unhappily combined with <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, i.e., to actually paste in mintty I need to press <kbd>Shift+Fn+Delete</kbd>, which is annoying.

Is it possible to bind the mintty paste op to <kbd>Shift+Delete</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is with a patch akin to

```
diff --git a/src/wininput.c b/src/wininput.c
index 20f2f3e..0f2958c 100644
--- a/src/wininput.c
+++ b/src/wininput.c
@@ -2033,7 +2033,8 @@ win_key_down(WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
       goto skip_shortcuts;

     // Copy&paste
-    if (cfg.clip_shortcuts && key == VK_INSERT && mods && !alt) {
+    if (cfg.clip_shortcuts && (key == VK_INSERT || key == VK_DELETE)
+        && mods && !alt) {
       if (ctrl)
         term_copy();
       if (shift)
```

I've tested it with the rev 0e65eec39 of https://github.com/mintty/mintty